# DB Connections persist after AWS Lambda update function code

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection-pooling, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have an AWS Lambda app in the VPC that listens on a single Kinesis shard - which is supposed to be 1-to-1, so I'm supposed to only have a single lambda instance running at the same time.

However, my db connections show old connections from the VPC address-space when I update the code. One possible explanation is that the old versions still live? Maybe they attempted termination but were blocked by DB-threads. Is that possible? How would I find out?

(Using Scala, Quill + JDBC + HicariCP for DB access)

Many thanks,
Victor.

Comment: Are you explicitly closing the connections in your Lambda function?

Comment: I'm using Quill to manage that for me; however, I found a(n ugly?) workaround, where I memoize the connection pooling, giving them a TTL in the cache (I'm using scalacache), and scheduling an explicit close event after that time expires `def x = memoizeSync (ttl) { val p = getPool; scheduleDestroy (p, ttl); return p }`. It kind of works, but is ugly and doesn't answer the question really.